# How to unhide collapsed parent list elements if a child element is checked on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-lists

I have a dynamic multilevel list that's generated by a database. On load, it hides all but the first level elements. I'd like it to unhide any parent item on load if one of the child elements are checked. I've gotten it to unhide the immediate parent, but not the main parent.

My list is set up like this:

```
<div class="form-row" id="existing-products">
    <label class="form_label">Choose products</label>
    <ul class="product-tree">
        <li>Main Product 1
            <ul>
                <li class="productList">Sub Product 1
                    <ul>
                        <li class="product"><input type="checkbox" name="prodCode[]" id="prodCodes" class="form_input" value="main1_sub1" checked />main1_sub1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="productList">Sub Product 2
                    <ul>
                        <li class="product"><input type="checkbox" name="prodCode[]" id="prodCodes" class="form_input" value="main1_sub2"  />main1_sub2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>               
        <li>Main Product 2      
            <ul>
                <li class="productList">Sub Product 1
                    <ul>
                        <li class="product"><input type="checkbox" name="prodCode[]" id="prodCodes" class="form_input" value="main2_sub1"  />main2_sub1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</div>
```

My script to toggle the list is:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var plus = $('<span> + </span>').addClass('plus');
    $('.product-tree li').has('ul').addClass('has-child')
    plus.prependTo('.has-child');
    $(".has-child").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        }
    );
    $('.has-child ul').hide();
    $('.product-tree input:checked').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().show(); // Does nothing?
        $(this).parent().parent().show(); // Will show Sub Product 1 when Main product 1 is clicked
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().show(); // Does nothing
    });

    $('.has-child .plus').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children("ul").toggle('slow');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the `prodCodes` id, HTML ids are meant to be unique. I would suggest updating your code (this update should have no effect of the problem at hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$('.product-tree input:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().show(); // Does nothing?
    $(this).parent().parent().show(); // Will show Sub Product 1 when Main product 1 is clicked
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().show(); // Does nothing
});
```

to:

```
$('.product-tree input:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parents().show(); // show all parent elements
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was almost too easy. Thanks!

Comment: @aynber It can actually be even simpler: `$('.product-tree input:checked').parents().show();` You can also provide a `selector` to the `parents` function to avoid matching every parents up to the `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
if($('.product-tree').find('input').is(':checked')) {
     $(this).parents().show();
}
```